# Float elipsis to the right of the div

Tags: html, css

Given a fixed size div, I need to show the ellipsis `...` on the right of the div after using text-overflow

```css
.fixed-container {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-container">
  <p class="text">
    Long text to be truncated and show the ellipsis
  </p>
</div>
```

I need to place the ellipsis to the right. So, change it from this

[image: Example]

To this:

[image: desired result]

Comment: This is not a javascript question.

Comment: Confusion: which image do you want the text to look like, the first or the second?

Comment: @CharlesBamford - I can't see how to do it without Javascript - do you have a method?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve it without Javascript. So I am happy to use it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible (with CSS alone), but for almost the same result you can use `text-align:justify-all;` on the text container, which stretches the line content a bit (i.e. equally distributes the words horizontally without enlarging the letter spacing) to fill the full line (the little space right of the last dot belongs to the dot character, so that can't be avoided).

```css
.fixed-container {
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-align:justify-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-container">
  <p class="text">
    Long text to be truncated and show the ellipsis
  </p>
</div>
```